# How to revalidate Joi.ref() with React-hook-form Controller?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, joi

I have 2 Controllers one for the **start date** and the other for the **end date**, each Controller has 2 inputs one for month and one for year.

The end date needs to always be higher than start date and I'm using Joi to validate that.

The problem is that react-hook-form is only running validation for `min(Joi.ref("startDate"))` on the onBlur effect of the **end date** and not for the onChange or onBlur of **start date**.

```
schema = Joi.object({
      startDate: Joi.date()
        .raw()
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        .less("now")
        .greater("1920-1-1"),
      endDate: Joi.date()
        .raw()
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        .less("now")
        .min(Joi.ref("startDate"))
        .allow(null)
});


const MonthYearInput = ({ name, checkbox }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  const monthRef = useRef();
  const yearRef = useRef();

  const getOptions = (list) => {
    if (!list) return null;
    const options = list.map((item) => {
      return (
        <option value={item.id} key={item.id}>
          {item.name}
        </option>
      );
    });
    return options;
  };

  const getDate = () => {
    const year = yearRef.current.value;
    const month = monthRef.current.value;
    const formattedMonth = month < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;
    return `${year}-${formattedMonth}-01`;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => {
          return (
            <>
              <select
                className={"form-select"}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  field.onChange(getDate());
                }}
                onBlur={field.onBlur}
                ref={monthRef}
                name={`${name}month`}
                defaultValue=""
              >
                <option key="0" value="" disabled>
                  Month
                </option>
                {getOptions(months)}
              </select>
              <input
                name={`${name}year`}
                type="number"
                step={1}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  field.onChange(getDate());
                }}
                onBlur={field.onBlur}
                ref={yearRef}
                placeholder="Year"
              />
              {error?.message && <div>{error?.message}</div>}
            </>
          );
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit festive-curran-qs8svg]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `trigger("endDate")` to the `onChange` events, so that it will manually revalidate.

[image: Edit festive-curran-qs8svg]